# Extjs Sass Theme Gem

Tags: css, extjs, themes, sass

Does anyone know some nice values to use with the modulate option for the extjs-theme gem?

https://github.com/extjs/extjs-theme

Answer (score 6):

// Here is my dark theme Don't forget to generate images for that with Sencha sdk tool

```
$theme-name: 'dark';
$base-color: #1c1c1c;

//panel section
$panel-header-background-gradient: color-stops(#2a2a2a, #191919);
$panel-border-color: #4d4d4d;
$panel-header-color: #888888;
$panel-frame-padding: 0px;
$panel-header-padding: 5px;


$panel-body-color: #888888;
$panel-frame-background-color: #1c1c1c;
$color: #888888;
$form-trigger-border-bottom: none;
$form-trigger-width: 24px;
//window
$window-background-color: #1c1c1c;
$window-header-color: #888888;

//menu
$menu-item-active-background-color: darken(#333333, 5);
$menu-item-active-border-color: #fff;

//datepicker
$datepicker-header-background-color: #333333;
$datepicker-border-color: #4d4d4d;
$datepicker-th-background-color: #404040;
$datepicker-selected-item-background-color: #505050;
$datepicker-item-hover-background-color: transparent;

//progress bar
$progress-border-color: #202020;
$progress-background-color: #f1f1f1;
$progress-bar-background-color: #ababab;

//tips
$tip-base-color: $base-color;
$tip-body-color: #fff;

//grid
$grid-header-color: #fff;
$grid-header-over-border-color: darken($base-color, 3);
$grid-header-background-color: adjust-color($base-color, $hue: 0deg, $saturation: 0%, $lightness: -16.078%) !default;
$grid-header-over-border-color: adjust-color($base-color, $hue: -0.175deg, $saturation: 25.296%, $lightness: -2.549%) !default;

//toolbar
$toolbar-border-color: null;
$toolbar-inner-border-width:0px;
$toolbar-background-gradient: color-stops(#232323, #121212);
$toolbar-separator-color: #686455;
$toolbar-text-color: #888888;

//btn group
$btn-group-background-color: #585858;
$btn-group-header-background-color: #353535;
$btn-group-border-color: #4d4d4d;
$btn-group-header-color: #666;

//form
$fieldset-header-color: #ddd;
$form-field-background-color: #111;
$form-field-color: #828282;
$form-field-border-color: #232323; 
$boundlist-border-color: #b5b8c8;

//acordion
$accordion-header-background-color: #999;

//tabs
$tab-base-color: #303030;
$tab-color-active: #eee;
$tab-color: #ddd;

//pagelet toolbar
$pagelet-background-gradient : color-stops(#d4d4d4,#dddddd);
$pagelet-background-color: #dddddd;

$tab-background-gradient: color-stops(#4d4d4d, #303030);
$tab-background-gradient-over: 'tab-over' !default;
$tab-background-gradient-active: color-stops(#5a5a5a, #303030);
$tab-background-gradient-disabled: 'tab-disabled' !default;

//buttons
$button-inner-border-color : #121212;
$button-default-color: #fff;
$button-default-base-color: #353535;
$button-default-base-color-over: #444444;
$button-default-base-color-focus: $button-default-base-color-over;
$button-default-base-color-pressed: #5f5f5f;
$button-default-base-color-disabled: adjust-color($base-color, $hue: 0deg, $saturation: -55.556%, $lightness: 12.745%) !default; //F7F7F7

$button-default-border-color: #121212;
//$button-default-border-color-over: #9d9d9d;
//$button-default-border-color-focus: $button-default-border-color-over;
//$button-default-border-color-pressed: $button-default-border-color-over;
//$button-default-border-color-disabled: adjust-color($button-default-base-color-disabled, $hue: 0deg, $saturation: 0%, $lightness: -8.627%) !default;

$button-default-background-gradient: color-stops(#444444, #2e2e2e);
$button-default-background-gradient-over: 'matte';
$button-default-background-gradient-focus: 'matte';
$button-default-background-gradient-pressed: color-stops(#444444,#666666);
$button-default-background-gradient-disabled: 'matte';

$button-default-background-gradient-color-stops: color-stops(#444444, #282828);
$button-default-background-gradient-color-stops-over: null;
$button-default-background-gradient-color-stops-focus: null;
$button-default-background-gradient-color-stops-pressed: color-stops(#444444, #666666);
$button-default-background-gradient-color-stops-disabled: null;


$button-toolbar-base-color: $button-default-base-color;
$button-toolbar-color: #ccc;
$button-toolbar-border-color: #131313;
//$button-toolbar-border-color-over: #9d9d9d;
//$button-toolbar-border-color-focus: $button-default-border-color-over;
//$button-toolbar-border-color-pressed: $button-default-border-color-over;
//$button-toolbar-border-color-disabled: adjust-color($button-default-base-color-disabled, $hue: 0deg, $saturation: 0%, $lightness: -8.627%) !default;

$button-toolbar-background-color: #171717;
$button-toolbar-background-color-over: #717171;
$button-toolbar-background-color-focus: #2B6893;
$button-toolbar-background-color-pressed: #444;
$button-toolbar-background-color-disabled: transparent;

$button-toolbar-background-gradient: color-stops(#171717,#1c1c1c);
$button-toolbar-background-gradient-over: color-stops(#1a1a1a,#1c1c1c);
$button-toolbar-background-gradient-focus: color-stops(#171717,#1c1c1c);
$button-toolbar-background-gradient-pressed: color-stops(#242424,#222222);
$button-toolbar-background-gradient-disabled: null;

$button-toolbar-background-gradient-color-stops: null;
$button-toolbar-background-gradient-color-stops-over: null;
$button-toolbar-background-gradient-color-stops-focus: null;
$button-toolbar-background-gradient-color-stops-pressed: null;
$button-toolbar-background-gradient-color-stops-disabled: null;

@import 'compass';
@import 'ext4/default/all';
```

Comment: @XenonN ... I'm having issues getting a bunch of Sencha ExtJS SASS variables to work.  I'm wondering if we can get in touch?  Specifically, I'm trying to use the cls config and overCls configs when the SASS variable in the scss file doesn't work.  I'm not sure how to do this.  Specifically, the background-color on form fields and the color on combo boxes aren't working.

Comment: Hi @MacGyver. Did you configure your extjs compass. It's really important to import extjs variables. It's under your /sass directory config.rb file

Comment: If yes then default variables are defined under "EXTJS/resources/themes/stylesheets/ext4/default/variables/" directory. So you can see which variables used to generate css files.

Comment: I can only give you a single upvote unfortunately- but this is one of the best answers I've seen on SO in terms of providing an excellent base for further customization